# Binding ItemsControl to a Double array

Tags: wpf, xaml, itemscontrol

The following *should* work as far as I can tell, unless I'm missing something obvious.

```
<ItemsControl x:Class="VGuidelines"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="200" d:DesignWidth="700">

  <ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
    <x:Array Type="sys:Double">

      <sys:Double>5</sys:Double>
      <sys:Double>121.0</sys:Double>
      <sys:Double>1301</sys:Double>
      <sys:Double>275</sys:Double>
      <sys:Double>322</sys:Double>
      <sys:Double>203</sys:Double>
      <sys:Double>223</sys:Double>
      <sys:Double>230</sys:Double>
      <sys:Double>37.5</sys:Double>
      <sys:Double>422</sys:Double>
    </x:Array>
  </ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Line X1="{Binding}" X2="{Binding}" Y1="0" Y2="1000" Stroke="Gray" Opacity="0.3" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

This should ideally display several lines in the ItemsControl. Instead it shows just one. I have tried several values, big and small, to no avail.

Can someone point out if I'm missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, an `ItemsControl` will arrange your lines in a vertically-oriented `StackPanel`.  This effectively stacks one very tall line on top of another, rather than drawing them in parallel as (I assume) you had intended.

Try setting your `ItemsControl` to use a `Canvas` for layout instead:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
  <ItemsPanelTemplate>
    <Canvas IsItemsHost="True" />
  </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
```

This will position each line relative to the top-left corner of the `Canvas`, using each line's various X and Y properties to determine its effective position:

[image: Screenshot of results]

FYI, if you want to better understand what ***was*** happening, you can temporarily add some scroll bars to the `ItemsControl` *before* making the change above.  Watch what happens as you scroll down :).

```
<ItemsControl.Template>
  <ControlTemplate TargetType="ItemsControl">
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
      <ItemsPresenter />
    </ScrollViewer>
  </ControlTemplate>
</ItemsControl.Template>
```

Comment: Ouch. I had a gut feeling that I was missing something basic. Thanks a ton.